# Proof that the space $L^1$ is complete in its metric

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, complete-spaces

I don't understand a particular detail of the proof on page 70 of Stein and Shakarchi's *Princeton Lectures in Analysis III.*

We consider a Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $L^1$ and choose a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $||f_{n_k+1} - f_{n_k}||_{L^1} \leq \frac{1}{2^k}$.

Then, we consider a function $f := f_{n_1} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(f_{n_k+1}-f_{n_k})$ and observe that $|f| \leq |f_{n_1}| + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |f_{n_k+1} - f_{n_k}| =: g$. Everything makes sense so far.

The next steps are where I become uncertain about the specific details.

The proof then observes that

$$\int|f_{n_1}| + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int|f_{n_k+1}-f_{n_k}| \leq \int|f_{n_1}| + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-k} < \infty$$

Here is the following questions I have:

1) How is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int|f_{n_k+1}-f_{n_k}|\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-k}$?

I know that $|f_{n_k+1} - f_{n_k}| \leq \frac{1}{2^k} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int|f_{n_k+1}-f_{n_k}| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} \int d\mu$, but that begs the question, what do we do with the $\int d\mu$? In fact, often times the book is so loose with the integration symbol at times that it's not even always clear what space we're integrating over. For instance, if we're integrating over $\mathbb{R^d}$, then $\int d\mu = \infty$, so I assume this can't possibly be the case. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis is not that $|f_{n_k+1} - f_{n_k}| \leq \frac{1}{2^k}$, but that 
$$
\|f_{n_k+1} - f_{n_k}\|_1 \leq \frac{1}{2^k}.
$$
That's exactly
$$
\int |f_{n_k+1} - f_{n_k}| \leq \frac{1}{2^k}.
$$

Comment: Oh!! Thank you so much - I knew my confusion was likely due to a simple misunderstanding. I can't accept this answer until after 12 minutes have passed, but I will be sure to do so!

Comment: Don't worry. And, eventually, you'll get used to the "loose" notation for integrals.